# Questions involving VBA date comparisons

Tags: excel, vba

I need to write some code that compares dates in an excel file and then high lights those rows of data based on the data evaluations. Essentially there are 3 columns in this file that have a standard Month/day/year format. I need to compare the day of all three columns to see if they are within a 3 day date difference "don't care about the month". If they are not within the 3 day date difference I want to high light them. An example of an OK comparison would be (10/1/2015,12/2/2015, 8/3/2015) I would not want to do anything with this row of data. Here is what I consider to be a "bad" date comparison (10/1/15, 11/3/2015, 8/5/2015). All the dates have to be within 3 days and as you can see there is a 4 day date difference between 10/1 and 8/5. How can I write something up like this to evaluate this?

Comment: Just a clarification, what do you mean by **standard XX/XX/XXXX format**? It seems to me from your examples that you mean `mount/day/year`, is that correct?

Comment: Month/date/year is correct. I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: "I need to write some code..." Good luck! We look forward to helping you once you actually have code to look at.

Comment: In VBA, always write dates the American way (mm/dd/yy)

Comment: Do you consider 10/31/15 and 11/01/15 to be more than 3 days different? E.g. two days that are contiguous on the calendar?

Comment: @iDevlop That only works if your OS local is set to US (or a country that has the same format).

Comment: @RacilHilan: I do not agree. I use french format dates but in vba I always write dates like #12/31/2015# and I noticed it's the only way to get consistent results across my international users.

Comment: @iDevlop I see what you mean. In this case, you're right, but it's a bit more complex than that. Let me start with VBA: If you give a `#...#` value to VBA, it tries to convert it to a valid date. So if you give it `#12/31/2015#` or `#31-12-2015#` it will successfully convert both to the same exact date. But for confusing dates like `#1-2-2000#`, you are right that it defaults to the US format. For that reason, I always use a clear format like `#1-apr-2000#` or the ISO standard `#2000-4-1#`. Those formats are crystal clear and VBA converts them perfectly.

Comment: @iDevlop Continuing my comment to the Excel (and Office): if you type any valid date in VBA Window (e.g. `#1-apr-2000#`), you will notice that Excel automatically converts the value to US format `#4/1/2000#`. This is the editor doing that, but it converts it in the same way that VBA does. To see how VBA works without the influence of the editor, create a test.vbs in Notepad and type in it `MsgBox #1-apr-2015#`, save it, and run it. You will see two things: 1) VBA correctly coverts the date 2) it displays the date according to your Regional Settings (change them and see how the message follows)

Answer (score 2):

You can just compare the *Max()* of the days to the *Min()* of the days with the **Array Formula**:

```
=IF(MAX(DAY(A1:C1))-MIN(DAY(A1:C1))>3,"fail","Close enough")
```

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

You can do the same functionality with *VBA* if that is needed.